# Cordova Content Security Policy frame-src error

Tags: html, ios, cordova, mobile, phonegap

```
Refused to frame '' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src *". Note that 'frame-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

I added "wkwebview" plugin for ios. But then I get this error. I don't have an iframe in my code. an iframe is automatically created. From "gap://ready".


**Error:**
[image: Error]

can you help me please

Comment: Have you checked the policy you are being accused of violating?

Comment: yes, added "frame-src *" but not working